# C command line password

Tags: c, command-line-interface

So I'm trying to create a C program where you must input the password on the command line, like
./login password1
And if the password is password1, it'll say something. If not, it prints another message. This is the code I have now:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if (argc < 2) {
    printf("usage: %s <password>\n", argv[0]);
  }
  char pass = "password";
  if (argc == pass) {
    printf("Right\n");
  } else {
    printf("Wrong\n");
  }
}
```

But it wont work.

Comment: Never too early to learn how to report issues. How exactly does it not work? What are the symptoms you see?

Comment: This isn't related to the problem you were asking about, but on some systems (Linux) the command line is visible to other processes (in `/proc/<pid>/cmdline`) so you should not consider command line arguments secret.  This info is probably available on several other systems (not sure).  (I think that this is silly)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char pass = "password";
```

You're trying to assign a string to a `char`. That won't work! Instead, you need need to declare `pass` as a `char[]` like this:

```
char pass[] = "password";
```

Next problem:

```
if(argc == pass)
```

`argc` is the number of command line arguments passed to your program (including the program name as the first). What you want is `argv`, which contains the actual arguments. Specifically, you probably want `argv[1]`.

You can't just go `argv[1] == pass` as that compares the location of the two strings. To compare strings, you need to use `strcmp()`. This function compares two strings and returns 0 if they're equal (there's good reason for that, but leave it for now). The former is like comparing two houses by checking if they have exactly the same street address; the latter is like comparing the houses with each other brick-by-brick. (sniped from @caf)

So the line becomes:

```
if (strcmp(argv[1], pass) == 0)
```

Put those fixes together and it should work. Please also work on improving the indentation of your code. It'll make it much easier to read, not only for others but yourself in a few weeks time.

Comment: The pointer comparison isn't *too* complicated: `argc[1] == pass` is comparing the *location* of the two strings; `strcmp()` compares the *contents* of them.  The former is like comparing two houses by checking if they have exactly the same street address; the latter is like comparing the houses with each other brick-by-brick.

Comment: @caf +1 Nice explanation! I hope you don't mine me adding that to my answer. If you do, feel free to rollback.

Comment: @caf: No, argc[1] is NOT the location of a string.  argc is an INT.  argc[1] has no meaningful value at all.  argv[1] is the string!

Comment: @abelenky: It should be obvious that that's a typo (SO has decreed that it's too late to fix it).

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing `argc` - the count of command line arguments - with the `"password"` string pointer.

For a start, you need to use `argv[1]` instead of `argc`. You also need to use a suitable `strcmp` function rather than just comparing the pointers.

Finally, inputting passwords via the command line is usually a bad idea due to security considerations. On many systems the command line may be visible to other users (eg via the "ps" command).

Comment: Its not for security reasons right now I know its a security issue if it's done like that